# How to run Cucumber test in NodeJS which is written in Typescript and ES6

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6, cucumberjs

What is the proper way to run CucumberJS BDD test written in Typescript and ES6.

I want to first transpile typescript code to es6 then use babel to make it es5.

[image]

I can run it from npm test like 
node_modules/.bin/babel-node node_modules/.bin/cucumber.js ./test/features
but how to add both typescript and babel? and is there any good test runner for backend like Karma which can be easily integrated with Webpack?